# Why do vectors not work in ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

H everyone, I can compile the following code in Xcode but I cannot do the same when using rosmake. Here is my .h file:

```
#ifndef __AStartAlgorithm__AStarAlgorithm__
#define __AStartAlgorithm__AStarAlgorithm__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class AStarAlgorithm{
   
public:

AStarAlgorithm();
void astar();
   
 void printmap(std::vector < std::vector<int> >map);

 private:

 };
#endif /* defined(__AStartAlgorithm__AStarAlgorithm__) */
```

Here is my .cpp:

```
#include "../header/AStarAlgorithm.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
AStarAlgorithm::AStarAlgorithm(){
    

}



void AStarAlgorithm::astar(){

   std::vector<std::vector<int> > map  = {{8,8,8,8,8,8,8},{8,0,0,0,0,0,8},{8,0,0,0,0,0,8},{8,0,1,0,0,2,8},{8,0,0,0,0,0,8},{8,0,0,0,0,0,8},{8,8,8,8,8,8,8}};
  
   // printmap(map);  
}

/*
void AStarAlgorithm::printmap(std::vector < std::vector<int> >map){
    
    for(int i = 0; i < map.size(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < map[i].size(); j++){
            if(map[i][j] <10){
                std::cout << "|"<<map[i][j] << " |";
            }else{
                std::cout << "|"<<map[i][j] << "|";
            }
            
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
*/
```

I want to print out the vector with the commented out code but the problem at the moment is just initialising the vector. Here is my error in ROS:

> /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/ucl_drone/src/trajectory/AStarAlgorithm.cpp:
> In member function ‘void
> AStarAlgorithm::astar()’:
> /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/ucl_drone/src/trajectory/AStarAlgorithm.cpp:17:154:
> error: in C++98 ‘map’ must be
> initialised by constructor, not by
> ‘{...}’
> /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/ucl_drone/src/trajectory/AStarAlgorithm.cpp:17:154:
> error: deducing from brace-enclosed
> initialiser, list requires #include
> <initializer_list>
> /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/ucl_drone/src/trajectory/AStarAlgorithm.cpp:17:154:
> error: deducing from brace-enclosed
> initialiser, list requires #include
> <initializer_list>
> /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/ucl_drone/src/trajectory/AStarAlgorithm.cpp:17:154:
> warning: extended initialiser lists
> only available with -std=c++0x or
> -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]   /home/jay/fuerte/sandbox/ucl_drone/src/trajectory/AStarAlgorithm.cpp:17:154:
> error: could not convert ‘{{8, 8, 8,
> 8, 8, 8, 8}, {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8},
> {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8}, {8, 0, 1, 0, 0,
> 2, 8}, {8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8}, {8, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 8}, {8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
> 8}}’ from ‘’ to
> ‘std::vectorstd::vector<int >’

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/94736/why-do-vectors-not-work-in-ros?/) by [JP](https://answers.ros.org/users/5695/jp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2013-10-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172053/c-can-i-statically-initialize-a-stdmap-at-compile-time

I'm guessing this is happening because Xcode uses LLVM/Clang and rosmake uses gcc.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2